# How to get an accessToken using MSAL library inside a Sharepoint Web Part?

Tags: sharepoint, azure-active-directory

I have developed a Sharepoint Web Part where I need to obtain the accessToken. To obtain the token I have used a MSAL library.

My problem is the next one: I'm logged in my Sharepoint but when the Web Part try to retrieve the accessToken something fails in the authentication and appears this error:

xxxx-web-part.js:1838 ClientAuthError: User login is required.
    at ClientAuthError.AuthError [as constructor] (https://localhost:4321/dist/xxx-web-part.js:2057:28)
    at new ClientAuthError (https://localhost:4321/dist/xxxx-web-part.js:630:28)
    at Function.7ZR7.ClientAuthError.createUserLoginRequiredError (https://localhost:4321/dist/xxxx-web-part.js:682:16)
    at https://localhost:4321/dist/xxx-web-part.js:2916:103
    at new Promise ()
    at UserAgentApplication.ZES5.UserAgentApplication.acquireTokenSilent (https://localhost:4321/dist/xxxx-web-part.js:2905:16)
    at UserAgentApplication.descriptor.value [as acquireTokenSilent] (https://localhost:4321/dist/xxxx-web-part.js:2543:38)
    at xxxWebPart.PlTk.xxxxWebPart.render (https://localhost:4321/dist/xxxx-web-part.js:1828:19)
    at xxxxWebPart.t._renderWithAccessibleTitle (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_27e01b6941bf5cdddecc695bd3bdbb95.js:21:585834)
    at https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_27e01b6941bf5cdddecc695bd3bdbb95.js:21:585352

How can fix this problem?. I would like that if I'm logged in Sharepoint obtain the accessToken without relogin into the system.

This is my code:

```
export default class MyWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart <IWebpartProps> {

  public render(): void {

  const config = {
      auth: {
          clientId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
      }
  };

  const myMSALObj = new UserAgentApplication(config);

  let accessTokenRequest = {
      scopes: ["user.read"]
  }

  myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(accessTokenRequest).then(function(accessTokenResponse) {
      // Acquire token silent success
      // call API with token
      let accessToken = accessTokenResponse.accessToken;
      let scopes = accessTokenResponse.scopes;
  }).catch(function (error) {
          //Acquire token silent failure, and send an interactive request
          console.log(error);
          if (error.errorMessage.indexOf("interaction_required") !== -1) {
              myMSALObj.acquireTokenRedirect(accessTokenRequest);
          }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found a workaround with something like this:

```
var accessTokenRequest = {
   scopes: ["user.read"],
   loginHint: preferred_username,
   extraQueryParameters: {domain_hint: 'organizations'}
}
```

Blessings and good night